# Unwanted 301 Redirect in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Url is getting an unwanted 301 redirected.
The url has a similar slug, for example, example.com/this/that-this gets redirected to example.com/this/that-this-asd.

There is no redirection on .htaccess ,cPanel or any redirect plugins.
This is what appears on network inspect tool image :
https://ibb.co/YLH7pXK

I've deleted slugs from database too using : DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug' .

How can you find the source of the redirection? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your `.htaccess` code, and with me you can speak in hebrew :) אהלן. אם יש לך גישה לקובץ htaccess בשרת, תעתיק את מה שכתוב בתוכו ותפרסם כאן (english for non-hebrew speakers: If you have access to this file, copy it and post it here)

Comment: אתה יכול להעלות את זה מסוגנן? זה מאוד מבולגן כשזה בשורה אחת. תערוך את השאלה בבקשה עם הקוד (השתמש ב-3 סימני רווח) או פרסם את הקוד ב-pastebin אם יהיה לך יותר קל...

Answer (score 0):

This is how WordPress works, unfortunately.

There is no full list of permalinks that WordPress knows.
Rather WordPress uses a bunch of RegEx search patterns and tries to make the best out of the input it gets through the URL.

So the page you get when you enter a URL in WordPress is always just the best guess there is.

For a single incident you will most likely find a good solution.
But there will most likely will be no general solution.

Remember to flush the permalink rules if something like this occures. Sometimes that solves problems.
See for explaination: https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/